# Pattern error rectification

Tags: java, arrays, function

I was trying to print this pattern as I have shown in the piece of code I gave.But somehow, I don't know what kind of mistake I made this wierd output has come along with the desired output.If you guys could help I would be really grateful

```
  /*2 6 12 20 30 42
 * 4 6 8 10 12
 * 2 2 2 2
 * 0 0 0
 * 0 0
 * 0
 * 
 */


public class patt {
    static int ar[]={2,6,12,20,30,42};
    public static void pattern(){
        int y=0,x=0;
        while( x<ar.length){
            int c[]=new int[6];

                    if(x+1>=ar.length){
                break;
            }
            else{
            c[x]=ar[x+1]-ar[x];
            System.out.print(c[x]+" ");
            ar[x]=c[x];
        }
            x++;
            }
            System.out.println();



    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
    patt ob=new patt();
    System.out.println("2 6 12 20 30 42");
for(int a=0;a<6;a++){
    ob.pattern();
}
}
}

The output is as follows,
2 6 12 20 30 42
4 6 8 10 12 
2 2 2 2 30 
0 0 0 28 12 
0 0 28 -16 30 
0 28 -44 46 12 
28 -72 90 -34 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the function 6 times (as the length of the array).
the problem is that you keep the changes in the static array, but then you run the following condition:

```
 if(x+1>=ar.length){
    break;
 }
```

the above is fine for the first run. but after the first run, there are supposed to be 5 elements left (after making differences between elements). yet, you will always run as the whole length of the array. that explains why you always have 5 elements printed on each line.
your solution is to define another static array which is the length, and then decrease that length after each run.
I have added a static length variable, replaced the condition listed above to look at it instead of always looking at the array length, and decreased the variable on each run.

```
public class patt {
    static int ar[]={2,6,12,20,30,42};
    static int length=ar.length;
    public static void pattern(){
        int y=0,x=0;
        while( x<ar.length){
            int c[]=new int[6];

                    if(x+1>=length){
                break;
            }
            else{
            c[x]=ar[x+1]-ar[x];
            System.out.print(c[x]+" ");
            ar[x]=c[x];
        }
            x++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        length--;


    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
    patt ob=new patt();
    System.out.println("2 6 12 20 30 42");
for(int a=0;a<6;a++){
    ob.pattern();
}
}
}
```